# MVC Core HTML Bootstrap button in Tag Helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-4

I scaffolded a table in MVC, and created a view.
This is the Edit button, I want change it, and make it blue bootstrap button
How would I conduct this?

**Original Code:**

```
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
        </td>
```

**Incorporate this blue button:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: Just add `class="btn btn-primary"` to the `<a>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add the class name to your `<a>` element to style it as bootstrap button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a>
```